# Updated code not showing in React Native Simulator

Tags: react-native

**The Problem:**

I am using the command `react-native run-ios` to run my app. However, since yesterday I have been having issues with the Reload (Command + R) command not updating the changes. I am still seeing the old app from a couple of days ago without the new changes.

What is interesting, however, is that with `Fast Refresh` enabled, if I make changes to the code. It automatically updates in the Simulator to the new code. However, as soon as I hit `Command+R` again it shows the old version of the app in the Simulator. But then if I make changes to the code and save it, the updates are automatically shown in Simulator (due to Fast Refresh).

**Question:**

Why is Fast Refresh able to show the results of my new code, but Command+R is showing the results of my old code?

**More info:**

Whenever I press `Command + R` I get the following showing in the Metro Bundler Window:

```
warn Error: not opened
 BUNDLE  [ios, dev] ./index.js ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓ 100.0% (1/1), done.

 MAP  [ios, dev] ./index.js ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓ 100.0% (1/1), done.
```

What exactly is it saying that is not opened?

Answer (score 0):

i have the same issue i resolve it when i restart my computer in fact there is bundle window from react that have been closed when i do restart it seem that windows keep in memory precedent running from older version.